# Why does Cut doesn't prevent Visual Prolog from finding another solutions

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

If we use `fail` in a predicate after the cut (`!`), it somehow still finds another solutoins using backtrack, but I think it shouldn't.
Consider the next example in Visual Prolog

```
implement main
    open core, stdio

class facts
    m : (integer M).

clauses
    m(1).
    m(2).
    m(3).
    m(4).

class predicates
    p : () failure.
clauses
    p() :-
        m(X),
        !,
        write(X),
        nl,
        fail.

clauses
    run() :-
        p().
    run().

end implement main

goal
    console::runUtf8(main::run).
```

Its output is

```
1
2
3
4
```

However, I expected only `1`, since, as written in the [official doc](https://wiki.visual-prolog.com/index.php?title=Language_Reference/Terms#cut_.28.21.29),

> Cut "!" removes all backtrack points created since the entrance to the current predicate, this means all backtrack points to subsequent clauses, plus backtrack points in predicate calls made in the current clause before the "!".

Moreover, if we run similar code in SWI-Prolog, its output will be `1` for `p :- m(X), !, write(X), fail.` and `1234` for `p :- m(X), write(X), fail.`, as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. But what happens if you remove the second `run()` ?

Comment: Second `run` stands just to ensure that `run` has `procedure` type, i.e. it gives only one solution (it's created by default). And since `p()` always fails, we have to put second `run` there.

Comment: Also, if we change to `p() :- m(X), !, write(X), nl.` and `run() :- p(), fail.` - everything works as expected, it prints only `1`. So the problem is when `!` and `fail` are met in the same clause